# python3 - list length required for loading file using array.fromfile

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I need to save and load an array of large numbers. The `array` module looks good, but I'm stuck on how to load a saved file using `fromfile`. This is the relevant code snippet:

```
def load_from_array():
    import array
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        data = array.array('i')
        data.fromfile(file, ????)
    return list(data)
```

The "????" is the number of elements in the list and is required. How do I know this number when the list is dynamic? I'm adding to the list, saving, and then opening again to add (or remove) more. I left it blank initially thinking it would default to 'all'. I then tried '-1' as for np arrays. Both error out. The docs simply say it is the number of elements you wish to load without offering an option for 'all'. If I need to know this number do I have to set up a counter variable and save that also? Or is there a better way to save and load a list of large integers? (Python 3)

Comment: You can use a very large number (more than can possible be) and catch the `EOFError` the array will still be updated. You can also use `frombytes(file.read())`.

Comment: Well that was embarrassingly easy! Thanks for the help. I've gone with catching the error.